# How to display Rails nested form static text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

In a rails 2.3.14 view, I have a fields_for nested within a form_for with the data presented in an HTML table.  Within the field_for I have a couple of model attributes that I want to display as simple static text, not as form fields.  All data shows up correctly within a text_field, but I cannot figure out to display it as plain text.  I know this must be a dumb question, but I can't figure it out and every form example has just form fields.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is really,  can you elaborate, possibly post an example of what you have now and what you WANT it to do?

Answer (score 7):

It would help to have some of your view code but wouldn't it be a matter of simply replacing the field tags with plain text? So for example if you have

```
<% fields_for :comment do |f| -%>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end -%>
```

You'd replace it with

```
<% fields_for :comment do |f| -%>
  <%= f.object.name %>
<% end -%>
```

Of course that rather defeats the purpose of having a form? It's possible I didn't understand the question.

Comment: It makes sense if he also has actual inputs he'd like to have as editable. This way allows him to display _which_ entry is being edited without allowing the identifying information to be modified.

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for, the insertion of `object` between the block param and the attribute I wanted.  I'd not seen anything like that and couldn't guess.  As @Caleb assumed, there are static values and form vars.  Thanks so much for the quick answer.

Comment: @RussK if this is what you were looking for, would you mind accepting the answer?